# Does a batch jobs admin page similiar to Spring batch admin page exist in TomEE server?

Tags: spring, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Is there any batch job manager console/GUI from where I can see the status of batch jobs in TomEE. I mean something like GUI in spring batch admin.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is requesting information about TomEE, not Spring Framework ;)

The implementation TomEE uses is called BatchEE, which is an Apache project. It would seem a GUI is available in the incubator: http://batchee.incubator.apache.org/gui.html

You might try deploying that and report back if it works with TomEE or not.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box , Spring Batch does not provide any GUI  .
Spring batch Admin can be used as a GUI , but that need to be connected with your spring batch project .
For the job status you can always check spring batch tables .